# Is there a way to add a custom formatting rule to netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

I am using netbeans 7.0 for php, and I want a specific type of formatting like so :

`if ( ! foo)`

There is currently no option to add spaces before and after `!`.
Can we get that in auto formatting for netbeans?

edit : oh, before you say there's a option for "unary operators", I don't want it screw with all other stuff, only `!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, custom formatting rules specific to the *unary not* operator is not possible with Netbeans.

You can see if someone has already submitted an enhancement request similar to yours, or submit your own at Netbeans's [Bugs, Feature Requests, and Enhancements](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) page. If one (or more) similar requests exist that would cover your request, then vote for them rather than submitting a new one.

Comment: Right. Accepting the answer bcoz you are clear in saying "no", saves my time... (Although I spent lot of time since Jul 14, 2011, searching for the way :) )